# Windows 7 remote assistance and sonicwall TZ210

Tags: windows-7, remote, sonicwall

Ive been trying to get remote assistance to work on Windows 7 professional PC behind a sonicwall TZ-210 firewall/router to another windows 7 professional PC. If I bypass the sonicwall device and assign an external IP, the RA works with invitation.  Or if I VPN into the network, that works as well.

But we really want RA to work without having to use either workaround and configure the sonicwall to get RA working.  At first I thought it I had to setup the firwall rules to allow IPV6 pass through.  I followed this [article](https://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=8000&SearchType=advanced&referrer=&gpn=&CustID=&bUseEditor=&keyword=MS+DirectAccess&rfield=&sortmethod=rel&usertype=&gpv=&catID2=&formaction=search&catID1=&IncludeHTML=&catID3=&TotalResults=4655&submitbutton=Go&match=and). That didnt solve it.

There is a test you can perform on MS Website which resulted in, "your router's NAT doesnt support it."

Also, I found this on windows 7 resource kit:

Remote Assistance will not connect in certain configurations. Specifically:
 Teredo cannot traverse a symmetric NAT. Remote Assistance can connect only across restricted NATs and cone NATs. In most cases, this is not a significant limitation, because the large majority of deployed NATs are either the restricted or cone variety. For more information on NAT traversal support in Windows 7, see Chapter 29, ―Deploying IPv6.‖

Is there any way of making this work using my current Sonicwall device ?

Answer (score -2):

~ Routers which have the feature to do NAT (NATTING environment), will not work.
~ Router actually do NAT when goes to the internet, easy connect feature does not work when nating is going on the router.

Comment: Well, the MS documentation says it does; it's even mentioned above. Only symmetric NAT wouldn't work.